# Session is not updated after ajax call in django

Tags: python, django, ajax

I'm struggling with session update handle after ajax call in django.
I used database session backend engine. but session is not updated database.
I consider  django_session table, but new session wes not inserted after ajax call.
This is my code.

View.py

```
def contact(request):

    contract = request.GET.get('contract ', 1)


    contract _session = request.session.get('contract ',False)
    if(not contract_session):

        request.session['contract '] = Contrato.objects.first().pk
        request.session.modified = True

   if Contract.objects.filter(id=contract).exists() and contract != request.session['contract ']:
        del request.session['contract ']
        contract = Contract.objects.get(id=contract)
        request.session.set_expiry(180000)
        request.session['contract '] = contract .id
        request.session.modified = True
   
        request.session.save()

   return  HttpResponse('ok')
```

settings.py

```
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE=3600,  # on hour in seconds
INSTALLED_APPS=[
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'rest_framework_jwt',
    'django_rest_passwordreset',
    'django_filters',
    'django_countries',
    'corsheaders',
    'rest_auth',
    'pwa',
],
MIDDLEWARE=[
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'beecoss_api.middleware.LoginRequiredMiddleware',
],
SESSION_ENGINE = "django.contrib.sessions.backends.db",
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = True,
```

template.html

```
var contract= $ ('#contract') .val ();

var url = "{% url 'url'%}";

$ .ajax ({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        data: {'contract':contract},
        success: function () {}
});
```

Also I was running server localhost:8000 and 127.0.0.1:8000

Comment: I feel that perhaps this might be some typo issues but I am not sure if this is just a mistake you made while editing the code to post it. Notice the extra spaces in `'contract '` in your views. While in your javascript you post as `{'contract':contract}` without the space.

Comment: Hi Abdul,  I got a request  in view.py successfully...